# \animategraphics is not animating the provided images

Tags: beamer, animations, animate, movie15

```
  \begin{figure}
       \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{10}{anim-}{0}{11}
  \end{figure}
```

I have anim-0.png to anim-11.png images. And I have included

```
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphics}
```

Still I am getting still image on previewing.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,tikz,movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphics}
\title{Data\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{2D Animation}
   \begin{figure}
        \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{10}{anim-}{0}{11}
     \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added the entire code. All those /usepackage are required at some other places in the document.

Comment: There are a lot of packages which are not needed for the MWE at all. `graphics` is outdated, you should use `graphicx` instead. And `hyperref` should basically be the last package to be loaded. The compilation stops at `subcaption` and the 'anim' files are not available.

Comment: On what PDF visualizer are you looking at it ? Evince, Okular, Acrobat Reader ?

Answer (score 2):

Beware to the PDF visualizer that you are using, not all include the feature of showing animated sequences.

Up to my knowledge, Evince is not but Acrobat Reader can display animated sequences. I didn't try with Okular.

Also, as Christian Hupfer said, use the `graphicx` package better than the old `graphics`.

Comment: Which PDF Viewers, besides Adobe Acrobat Reader, display animations correctly? I saw Foxit can handle them but not always.

Comment: Okular does work as well. I did not manage to get it to run in evince.